# Convert to Standard Form of a Circle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I am trying to convert 
$$x^2 + y^2 - \frac{2(px + qy)}{p^2 + q^2 - r^2} + \frac{1}{(p^2 + q^2 - r^2)} = 0$$ 
and 
$$x^2 + y^2 - \frac{2(px + qy)}{p^2 + q^2 - r^2} + \frac{1}{((p^2 + q^2 - r^2)^2)} = 0$$

to circles of standard form $$(X-A)^2 + (Y-B)^2 = R^2$$. I've tried all sorts of algebraic manipulations, but I'm struggling! Could someone please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being posed is confusing matters by introducing some terms that you can initially treat as opaque.  For instance, let $\omega = p^2+q^2-r^2$ first, and then you have, for the first part,

$$
x^2 + y^2 - \frac{2(px+qy)}{\omega} = -\frac{1}{\omega}
$$

The next key is to break the center fraction apart into its two components, and redistribute:

$$
x^2 - 2\frac{p}{\omega}x + y^2 - 2\frac{q}{\omega}y = -\frac{1}{\omega}
$$

Complete the squares:

$$
x^2 - 2\frac{p}{\omega}x + \frac{p^2}{\omega^2} +
y^2 - 2\frac{q}{\omega}y + \frac{q^2}{\omega^2} =
        -\frac{1}{\omega} + \frac{p^2}{\omega^2} + \frac{q^2}{\omega^2}
$$

Factor:

$$
\left(x - \frac{p}{\omega}\right)^2 + \left(y - \frac{q}{\omega}\right)^2 =
    \frac{-\omega+p^2+q^2}{\omega^2}
$$

Now substitute $\omega = p^2+q^2-r^2$ back in:

$$
\left(x - \frac{p}{p^2+q^2-r^2}\right)^2 +
\left(y - \frac{q}{p^2+q^2-r^2}\right)^2 =
    \frac{r^2}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} = \left(\frac{r}{p^2+q^2-r^2}\right)^2
$$

The second part can be done in essentially the same way, although it looks a little more tedious because of the squared constant term.  Still, the same principles apply, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Complete the square:
$$ \left( x - \frac{p}{p^2+q^2-r^2} \right)^2 + \left( y - \frac{q}{p^2+q^2-r^2} \right)^2 = ? $$
To find the ?, expand both terms on the left and use the previous equality to work out what the term on the right should be:
$$ \frac{p^2+q^2}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} - \frac{1}{p^2+q^2-r^2} = \frac{p^2+q^2-p^2-q^2+r^2}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} = \frac{r^2}{p^2+q^2-r^2} $$
in the first case, and
$$ \frac{p^2+q^2}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} - \frac{1}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} = \frac{p^2+q^2-1}{(p^2+q^2-r^2)^2} $$
in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok what you can do is:

Given $(X-A)^2+(Y-B)^2=R^2$, try expanding it and see: 
$X^2-2XA+A^2+Y^2-2YB+B^2=R^2$

You are looking for each of the terms of this expansion which you can do by expanding also the top one, such as:

$$x^2+y^2-\frac{2(px+qy)}{p^2+q^2-r^2} + \frac{1}{p^2+q^2-r^2}=$$
$$x^2-2\frac{p}{p^2+q^2-r^2}x+y^2-2\frac{q}{p^2+q^2-r^2}y+\frac{1}{p^2+q^2-r^2}=0$$

See if you can find anything from that and maybye you'll get what you looking for.